# How to write criteria to check multiple conditions for mongoOperations in java

Tags: java, mongodb, criteriabuilder

Suppose collection is having 3 documents. For example:

{"document" : "001",
"requestType" : "A",
"valid" : "true"},

{"document" : "002",
"requestType" : "A",
"valid" : "false"},

{"document" : "003",
"requestType" : "B"}

**Each document has 2 attribute "requestType","document" mandatory. "valid" attribute is optional**

What I want to achieve:

write criteria for a query that will check:

1-> what is the requestType of an document

if the requestType is "A" I need to check valid attribute is true.

else fetch the other "requestType" documents as well.

**Final result in the response should be:**

{"document" : "001",
"requestType" : "A",
"valid" : "true"},

{"document" : "003",
"requestType" : "B"}

What I tried:

```
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
//others criteria are there as well thats why used orOperator
    criteria.orOperator(
                        Criteria.where("requestType").is("A"),
                        Criteria.where("valid").is(true)
                );
    final Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
```

**It is providing response as:
{"document" : "001",
"requestType" : "A",
"valid" : "true"},**

**But I needed
{"document" : "003",
"requestType" : "B"}
in the response as well**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the query you are running needs a little update, currently the query makes `{$or:[{ requestType:A}, {valid:true}]}` but it should be: `{$or:[$and:[{ requestType:A}, {valid:true}],"valid":{$ne:"A"}]}`

```
  criteria.orOperator(
     Criteria.where("requestType").is("A").andOperator(Criteria.where("valid").is(true)),
      Criteria.where("requestType").ne("A")

  );
```